# Python append values to list with headers

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a `list` with headers which looks like this:

```
data = [['name', 'year', 'turn_over', 'net_result']]
```

Now I want to append the following to `data`:

```
name = soup.find('title').get_text().strip()
year = soup.find('span').get_text().strip()
turn_over = soup.find('div').get_text().strip()
net_result = soup.find('td').get_text().strip()
```

I thought I could use:

```
data.extend(zip(name, year, turn_over, net_result))
```

Since `name`, `year` et.c. are strings, `zip` splits them on each character. So I can `append` all `strings` to separate `lists` and then use `data.extend(zip())` on those lists:

```
all_names = []
all_years = []
all_turn_overs = []
all_net_results = []

all_names.append(name)
all_years.append(year)
all_turn_overs.append(turn_over)
all_net_results.append(net_result)

data.extend(zip(all_names, all_years, all_turn_overs, all_net_results))
```

But is there a smarter way?

Comment: Are you trying to add a single row of data, or multiple rows?

Comment: why is it a list inside a list ?

Comment: yeah, sorry. trying to add multiple rows.

Comment: so, trying to add multiple lists inside the main list ?

Comment: yeah, or rather add multiple strings inside main list with headers. I already know how to add multiple lists to another list.

Comment: If you need the intermediate lists then this is good. If you only need the final output, you can just add each item to data as you have it. Also it lines up pretty well with a db table, or a list of class objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you can use dict for you data:

```
data = {'name':[string1,string2,...], 
        'year':[name':[string1,string2,...], 
        'turn_over':[name':[string1,string2,...], 
        'net_result':[name':[string1,string2,...]
       }


from collections import defaultdict
data = defaultdict(list)
data['name'].append(name_sting)
data['year'].append(year_sting)
data['turn_over'].append(turn_over_sting)
data['net_result'].append(net_result_sting)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this with a list of tuples without headers. The headers would be implicit in the data structure and explicit in the program code.

```
data=[]
data.append((name, year, turn_over, net_result))
```

If having the field names in the data object is important you could use named tuples.

```
import collections
Webpage = collections.namedtuple('Webpage', 'name year turn_over net_result')
data=[]
data.append(Webpage(name, year, turn_over, net_result))
```